# htaccess 301 Redirect with Special Character Doesn't Work

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to 301 redirect this URL `https://example.com/@guest` to `https://example.com/forum`
I tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /@guest /forum
```

Unfortunately It redirects to `https://example.com/forum?`

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: The code redirects `https://example.com/@guest` to `https://example.com/forum?` but I want to redirect to `https://example.com/forum`

Comment: The htaccess is so huge. I tried to delete cache and tried again and now it redirects to `https://example.com/forum?@guest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule with `RewriteRule` that supports regex and precise matching:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^@guest /forum? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Test it after clearing browser cache again.

`?` in redirected URL will strip off any query string.

Comment: It still redirects to `https://example.com/forum?@guest` I already delete the cache

Comment: For some weird reason it redirects to `https://example.com/forum?@guest`. I tried adding to top and btm of my htaccess. Can you just add another redirect to redirect this `https://example.com/forum?@guest` to `https://example.com/forum` maybe it can help.

Comment: I have tested this rule on my local Apache it redirects to `https://example.com/forum` . You can also try this rule: `RewriteRule ^@guest /forum? [L,NC,R=301]` and clear cache.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with your last comment code. It works like a charm